# Python struct library says bytestring is incorrect length

Tags: python, serialization, struct

I'm trying to write a serialization library and am running into an issue. struct.unpack() is telling me that it needs a bytestring that is 112 bytes long, but the bytestring is very clearly 112 bytes long, as you can see:

```
>>> b = a.serialize(a.genericHeader() + [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
>>> b
'\xb0\xba\xfewGRYP\x00\x15\x00r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x05\x00\x06\x00\x07\x00\x08'
>>> c = a.deserialize(b)
112
6
['\xb0', '\xba', '\xfe', 'w', 'G', 'R', 'Y', 'P', '\x00', '\x15', '\x00', 'r', '
\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '
\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x01', '
\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '
\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '
\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '
\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '
\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '
\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '
\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '
\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x02', '\x00', '\x03', '\x00', '\x04', '\x00', '\x05']
['\x00', '\x06', '\x00', '\x07', '\x00', '\x08']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "GS1000_messages.py", line 775, in deserialize
    data = struct.unpack(">QHHHHQQQQQQQQQQQHHHH", data)
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 112
```

Here's where I unpack the bytestring:

```
@staticmethod
def deserialize(serialized):

    implicit = list(serialized[0x70:])
    data = list(serialized[:0x70])
    print len(data)
    print len(implicit)
    print data
    print implicit
    data = struct.unpack(">QHHHHQQQQQQQQQQQHHHH", data)
```

You can see from the 112 it prints that data is 112 bytes long, so why is struct.unpack telling me it isn't the right size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-read the error message. The problem isn't the length, it's the data type. [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) requires incoming data be a string, and you're passing it a list:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a **string** argument of length 112
```

Comment: Yeah that was pretty obvious looking at it now, thanks